# Determine the truth value of the following statements.

Tags: logic

1. $(\forall x \in \Bbb R)( \sqrt{x^2}= x)$ .
2. $(\exists x \in \Bbb R)(\exists y \in \Bbb R):(x^2 + y^2=9 )$.
3. $(\exists x \in \Bbb R)(\forall y \in \Bbb R)(x + y =7 )$.

Comment: You should say what part of this you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

Statement ‘3.’ is false because there does not exist any real number $x$ such that $x+y=7$ is true for any real number $y$, indeed $x+y=7$ is true only for $y=7-x$.

Comment: @Letsintegreat Angelo is right.

Comment: @DanielV Oh Thanks!, But can you find a reference to this?

Comment: @Letsintegreat If number (3) is true (which it isn't), then there would have to be a single value of $x$ for which the assertion is true (for example) for **both** $y = 2$ and $y=3$.  Is it possible for a **single** value of $x$ to make the equation **simultaneously** true for **both** values of $y$?

Comment: No, it is not possible. That is why statement ‘$3.$’ is false.